# Python os.environ.__getitem__ raise KeyError from None

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, moto

Trying to run a python test for an AWS Lamdba Function. The test code will not run and outputs this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/ordep81/Documents/cloud-challenge/Lambda/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    region_name = os.environ['REGION_NAME']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key) from None
```

Here is the code initializing the variable app.py :

```
import boto3
import json
import os

# create the client outside of the handler
region_name = os.environ['REGION_NAME']
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')
table_name = os.environ['TABLE_NAME']
```

Code running the test test_app.py

```
import boto3
import os
import unittest
from app import lambda_handler
from moto import mock_lambda
```

Answer (score 2):

The error comes up because the environment variables are not available on the processor script.  To visualise this, you could simply output the os.environ and see if your variable appears there.

```
print(os.environ)
```

If it doesn't appear, it means that the variable is not loaded on the script and therefore throws the error 'os.environ.**getitem** raise KeyError from None'

Assuming that you have the variables (key-value pairs) defined in the .evn file, to import them on your script while testing on your LOCAL machine, you could use the [dotenv library](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

First install dependency:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Within the script:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
print(os.environ['FOO'])
```

I've also written an article on the same topic [here](https://smart5.co.uk/article/28/python-os.environ.__getitem__-raise-keyerror-from-none)

Answer (score 1):

The region name for lambda is in `AWS_REGION` environment variable. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime):

> AWS_REGION – The AWS Region where the Lambda function is executed.

Thus, instead of

```
region_name = os.environ['REGION_NAME']
```

you should use

```
region_name = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
```

In the Lambda console you can provide value for `TABLE_NAME` as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

To set environment variables for tests, you can do the following before you will want to access them:

```
os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'
os.environ['TABLE_NAME'] = 'my-table'
```

Comment: still get same error if fixed or commented completely out.

Comment: @Ordep81 You have to run the code in lambda function. `AWS_REGION` variable is available there. `TABLE_NAME` is your custom variable, thus you have to provide it yourself.

Comment: Yes the first code snippet is my lambda function. This is for a cloud formation template, now im trying to run a test before it deploys. The test code is throwing an error since it python has an issue w/ __getitem__

Comment: @Ordep81 I added code snipped showing how to set these env variables in python before you use them.

Comment: do I set these in my python code? As I already have them set in my Lambda function

Comment: @Ordep81 This is for your test function. You wrote in your test function you don't have them.

Answer (score 1):

The correct name from the environment variable is `AWS_REGION` so you should change the line to

```
region_name = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
```

Also, since it's likely that you will use a "default" region in your project/app/product most of the time, it's customary to use this form

```
DEFAULT_REGION = "us-east-1"
region_name = os.environ.get("AWS_REGION", DEFAULT_REGION)
```

Comment: I still get the same error, even if I comment that line out then the error will go down to os.environ['TABLE_NAME']

Comment: In general you should always guard yourself against possibly missing environment variables, since I'm not aware of a `TABLE_NAME` variable in the AWS Lambda spec it seems that you should either provide the value yourself or use a default.